# How to use R to convert column of ISO Timestamp data into POSIXt?

Tags: r, datetime, unix-timestamp, lubridate

I have a data frame that looks something like this:

tbl <- data.frame(ISO_Timestamp = c(1612972204, 1612972214, 1612972224, 1612972234),
S1 = c(7056, 7101.1, 5145, 2198))

I want to convert the ISO_timestamp column into a date-time POSIXt format. I am able to convert single ISO_Timestamp timestamp objects like this:

```
lubridate::as_datetime(1612988995)
[1] "2021-02-10 20:29:55 UTC"
```

I tried this to convert the entire column but it is not working.

```
data_1 <- tbl %>% 
mutate(date_time = as_datetime(`ISO_Timestamp`))
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 Warning messages:
1: Problem with `mutate()` input `date_time`.
x All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
ℹ Input `date_time` is `as_datetime(`ISO_Timestamp`)`. 
2: All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column name didn't had any spaces

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
tbl %>% 
  mutate(date_time = as_datetime(ISO_Timestamp))
```

-output

```
# ISO_Timestamp     S1           date_time
#1    1612972204 7056.0 2021-02-10 15:50:04
#2    1612972214 7101.1 2021-02-10 15:50:14
#3    1612972224 5145.0 2021-02-10 15:50:24
#4    1612972234 2198.0 2021-02-10 15:50:34
```

Comment: Sorry, the issue with the column name was just a typo in this question. I edited it to fix that. I am still getting the "all formats failed to parse. No formats found" error. I checked to make sure that all of the data in the data.frame are in the same format shown. I even get this same error when I use base R like this: as_datetime(tbl_1$ISO_Timestamp). Any ideas?

Comment: I figured it out. If you explicitly convert the column into integer type rather than character it parses it fine with the code above.

Comment: @JustinAndrew If there are multiple datetime formats use `parse_date_time(ISO_Timestamp, yourformats)`

Comment: @JustinAndrew with the example showed, it is all working for me